# Is the Fourier transform a conformal map on $L^{2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, inner-products, conformal-geometry

I read that a conformal map is one that preserves the angles. I know nothing more about conformal maps. I don't know where to find a generalized definition of a conformal map, but I guess that if $f:U\to U$ is a map defined from and to a space endowed with an inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$, as angles can be defined through the inner product, it should suffice for a conformal $f$ to have the following property:

$$<f(u),f(v)>=<u,v>\qquad\forall\ u,v\in U$$

Now, let's say that $U\equiv L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\equiv\mathscr{F}$. Then

$$<\mathscr{F}f,\mathscr{F}g>=<f,g>\qquad\forall\ f,g\in U$$

by the Parseval-Plancherel theorem. So, is it the Fourier transform a conformal map on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The Fourier transform preserves the inner product, hence...

Comment: Yep, but as I said, I only guessed the definition. So am I right?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=define:+conformal+map  :)

Comment: Yes, when you think about it angles are inherently related to the 2-dimensional plane determined by the two vectors in question. But then any question of angles is going to reduce to one in finite dimensions (i.e. $\le 2$)

Comment: We're still talking about abstract angles between functions, not factual angles on the complex plane (or whichever $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), right?

Comment: We are speaking of angles between elements of an inner product space. Whether they are functions or formal symbols or whatever, there is still a notion of angle between them.

Comment: Alright, just checking. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a conformal map preserves angles (but not necessarily length).

In the case of an inner product space, since the angle between two vectors $v,w$ is defined to be the arccosine of thrle quantity $\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{|v||w|}$, a conformal map $c:V\to W$ is one that preserves this quantity. In particular, since $|v| = \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, if $c$ preserves the inner product, it must preserve angles, hence is conformal.

Some more general context: a conformal map of Riemannian manifolds, $c:(M,g)\to (N,h)$, is one so that the angle between two tangent vectors $v_p,w_p\in T_pM$ is equal to the angle between their images $dc(v_p),dc(w_p)\in T_{c(p)}N$. As an exercise, you should prove that this is equivalent to the existence of a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $c^*h = fg.$

Comment: Very clear, thank you.

Comment: Surely your definition of angle is off:  that quantity is the cosine of the angle.

Comment: @AdamHughes Surely I wouldn't make such an embarrassing mistake! :) thanks for the catch.